# Instantiate IAsyncCollectors to manually invoke webjob function

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous, azure-webjobs-triggered

Is it possible to invoke a webjobs function, whose arguments consist of IAsyncCollectors decorated by e.g. [Queue] or [EventHub] attributes, passing in the same type of collectors to the function as the webjobs SDK would?

For example, we want to trigger a webjobs function on a timer which implements its own distributed locking. The webjobs function we want to invoke is also triggered by the webjobs SDK using the TimerTrigger, and we want to use the same IAsyncCollectors in both cases.

Comment: What the meaning of invoke webjobs function whose argumentis `IAsyncCollectors` as the webjobs SDK. Do you want to use TimeTrigger and queuetrigger with `IAsyncCollectors` in a single webjobs function?

Comment: I have a webjobs function that is triggered using a TimerTrigger, and also has IAsyncCollector parameters decorated with the [Queue] attribute. When webjobs SDK triggers this function based on the TimerTrigger, it passes in instances of the IAsyncCollectors.

What I want to be able to do is call the webjob function manually (not based on the SDK's TimerTrigger) but pass in the same types of IAsyncCollectors as the SDK would if it were being called based on the TimerTrigger.